# SonataPageBundle add new block on page with admin section

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have install [sonatapagebundle](/questions/tagged/sonatapagebundle) and generate all route with the command line :

```
php app/console sonata:page:update-core-routes --site=all
```

when I'm going on the composer page in the admin section for my public homepage, I've got this message :

```
Warning! Before using the composer option, you need to configure the template layout.
The configuration must be done in the sonata_page.templates section.

See a complete exemple here:

sonata_page:
# [...]
templates:
    default:
        path: 'ApplicationSonataPageBundle::demo_layout.html.twig'
        name: 'default'
        containers:
            header:
                name: Header
            content_top:
                name: Top content
            content:
                name: Main content
            content_bottom:
                name: Bottom content
            footer:
                name: Footer
        matrix:
            layout: |
                HHHHHHHH
                TTTTBBBB
                TTTTBBBB
                TTTTBBBB
                TTTTBBBB
                CCCCCCCC
                CCCCCCCC
                FFFFFFFF

            mapping:
                H: header
                T: content_top
                C: content
                B: content_bottom
                F: footer
```

But my config.yml have this line for the sonata_page category. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem... The problem was that in config.yml I had twice

```
templates:
    default: {path: 'SonataPageBundle::layout.html.twig', name: default }
...

templates:
    default:
        path: 'ApplicationSonataPageBundle::layout.html.twig'
        name: 'default'
...
```

So check again your config.yml file and remove duplicates if case.